# GPS tracking and Web mapping?

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps, gps, tracking, here-maps

We are developing a tracking software and we are the stage where we test the reliability of our location stigma on the following web-maps

- Google Map
- Nokia HERE
- Open Street Map (OSM)

We observe that our location appears accurate on Google maps, however when switched to Nokia or Openstreet there is a discrepancy of around 40-50 metres from our actual location. 
Most importantly our GPS position accuracy is around 2m.

Could it be inaccuracy of map calibration or any similar problems known by anyone?

Comment: I know Nokia have Assisted-GPS in their API under nokia.maps.positioning.Manager  http://www.nokia.com/in-en/support/product/nokia-maps-309/userguidance/?action=singleTopic&topic=GUID-9805284D-7193-400A-8F36-ADBEEE98A0C0

Comment: Have you checked that the projection of the tracker location and the underlying map are identical in all situations/combinations?

Comment: Which are are you in?

Comment: Are you zooming using satellite view in any of the providers to the point that it switches to oblique view?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using same location (latitude and langitude) on all maps, then there is little possibility of descrepancy due to location. It is possible that the maps have descrepancy among themselves. You can compare accuracy of google and osm map at [mapcompare](http://tools.geofabrik.de/mc/). See if there is any descrepancy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I have observed this discrepancy in Google maps and OpenStreetMap data. Basically shape or position of the road would be slightly different. So if you perform map matching (google snap_to_road or OSRM match) with respect to one data source and visualize it on the other there would be some inconsistencies.

Two simple ways to tackle this:

1. Use the same maps backend for map matching and visualization.
2. Be a good citizen and actually go to https://www.openstreetmap.org and    edit the road if you think it's incorrect. I don't know a way to apply these corrections at scale.

I am developer at [HyperTrack](https://www.hypertrack.com/). Do check us out as we have already solved these kind of problems for you.